# How can we send mail (using SMTP which in turn uses TCP) to more than one client?

Tags: networking, tcp, smtp, multicast

It has been written in the book Computer Networking - A Top Down Approach by James F. Kurose and Keith W. Ross (5th Edition) that :
Multicasting - the transfer of data from one sender to many receivers in a single send operation - is not possible with TCP.

Then, how is it possible using SMTP (which uses TCP) to send a mail to more than one client?

Comment: Because you send mail over a unicast connection to a *mail server*, which then sends it on to each addressee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP/IP is only the transport protocol for the network. SMTP is the protocol that controls mail delivery.

SMTP does not directly send mail to more than one "client." When you send mail through SMTP, it connects to a single mail server to send the outgoing message.

The mail server then routes the mail to other known mail servers. The server you initially send to may not even know the server that is the end point for the mail. The simplest explanation is that the mail server uses the mail servers it knows to discover the routing for the message. This is what makes SMTP robust is that it uses discoverable routing.